# All relations among degree n monomials in n variables

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In the course of my work, I have run into the problem of finding exactly all relations among degree $n$ monomials in $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$, with specific interest in the case $n=3$ (e.g. $x_1^2 x_2 \cdot x_3^2 x_2 = (x_1x_2x_3)^2$). The result is simple for $n=2$, but extending the methods used to higher $n$ has proven intractable.

Is anyone aware of the existence of a solution to this, perhaps even just for $n=3$?

Comment: What do you mean by relations?
Taking both sides to the power $k$ in your example gives a new relation?

Comment: More precisely, I am looking for the kernel of the map $k[w_1, \dotsc, w_{10}] \to k[x_1 x_2 x_3, x_1^3, x_2^3, x_3^3, x_1^2 x_2, x_1^2 x_3, \dotsc]$ which takes $w_1 \mapsto x_1 x_2 x_3, w_2 \mapsto x_1^3$, etc. in terms of its generators.

Comment: You are asking for the first syzygy module of the $n$th Veronese subalgebra of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. A relevant paper is http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.4796.pdf.